# microsoft onedrive sdk usage in android project

Tags: android, onedrive

I need to integrate Onedrive SDK  in my project.i  referred these links: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android#11-install-aar-via-gradle,
https://dev.onedrive.com/.

Can anyone explain the steps for integrating onedrive sdk with my application

Comment: If you are using gradle, you should just add the repository and the dependencies to your project.  If you want to see an example project that depends on this library look at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-android

Comment: I have tried by adding repository and dependencies in external jar file >in bulid.gradle file but I could not able to build  .

Comment: have u done integration . I m also looking for same. If done pls guide.